# Register instance creator for generic type with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have the following configuration in Simple Injector:

```
c.Register<IQueryable<Entity1>>(() => c.GetInstance<IDomainQueryFactory>().Query<Entity1>());
c.Register<IQueryable<Entity2>>(() => c.GetInstance<IDomainQueryFactory>().Query<Entity2>());
c.Register<IQueryable<Entity3>>(() => c.GetInstance<IDomainQueryFactory>().Query<Entity3>());
c.Register<IQueryable<Entity4>>(() => c.GetInstance<IDomainQueryFactory>().Query<Entity4>());
...
```

The `IDomainQueryFactory` factory is responsible for creating the instances of `IQueryable<TEntity>`. Some class (like MVC controller) then declares dependency only on `IQueryable<Entity1>`.

I am wondering if there is some way of writing these registrations with a single command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this, because Simple Injector favors composition using types over functional composition. This means that Simple Injector does not easily allow you to register a generic method to be used in the registration process, just as you would be able to use a generic type.

So to reduce the amount of boilerplate code and prevent having to update the configuration on each new entity, you will have to create a generic `IQueryable<T>` implementation and register that. This is how this implementation would look like:

```
public sealed class DomainQueryFactoryQueryable<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
    private readonly IDomainQueryFactory factory;

    public DomainQueryFactoryQueryable(IDomainQueryFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public Type ElementType { get { return this.GetQuery().ElementType; } }
    public Expression Expression { get { return this.GetQuery().Expression; } }
    public IQueryProvider Provider { get { return this.GetQuery().Provider; } }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetQuery().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    private IQueryable<T> GetQuery() { 
        return this.factory.Query<T>();
    }
}
```

And you can register this as follows:

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(DomainQueryFactoryQueryable<>));
```

Comment: Thank you, Steven, for the explanation and solution. I will look into this soon.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. I will try to get more into the type-composition over functional-composition thinking.

Comment: Have you noticed how this snippet is around 20 times longer than the functional option (if it was supported)? One begins to wonder about design decisions...

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: I agree that it would be nice to be able to do functional composition, but the thing is, that C# isn't very well suited for that. Simple Injector especially targets C# users. We tried multiple times to get a pleasant API that allowed registration of generic methods, but we never got it right. It became extremely ugly in C#. But if you have any ideas, let's start [a discussion on Github](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/new). I think the whole Simple Injector team is very interested in this (I sure am).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any more time to devote to SI, but here are two ideas: (1) use MEF attributed model with methods, properties, and fields used as factories. (2) specify a template as expression, something like: `container.Register( () => new MyClass<G.T1, G.T2>().MyMethod() )`, where `G.T1` and `G.T2` are dummy types defined by SI and used as stand-ins for generic arguments.

Comment: @fyodorsoikin: Thanks for the suggestions. About 1: the use of attributes is out of the question, which [violated one of Simple Injector's basic design principles](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/principles.html#vendor-lock-in). We've looked at 2, but the use of filled in types is ugly to read and the user will have to explicitly state whether he wants to use that particular method or any generic version. That gets really ugly; but, it's a possibility.